# Create URL for a Work Item in Filenet

Tags: filenet-p8, filenet-workplace

I want to attach the URL of a task in a user's Filenet P8 inbox and send it over in an email so that when clicked will directly open the task linked. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your front end. If you're using Workplace, then it's definitely possible. Just use the link that Workplace generates in the "Tasks" section.

HTH!

Comment: Thx. For the rest, here is the link. http : //servername:portnumber/WorkplaceXT/Tasks.jsp